# Log message on Spring AOP Aspect start up

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, aspects

how to log message on Spring AOP aspect start up? 
The only way I see is to specify flag on every intercepted method and check. May be any other options? Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify please.  Do you want to log the AOP or the method it wraps?

Comment: The best case  - aspect bean created, then log message about this logged. I don't want to intercept all the needed method calls and check inside whether message was logged or not.

Comment: I will vote for the question to be closed because it is unclear. Please edit the question, improve it by adding **code**. The code should communicate your situation and what you want to achieve. Then I will retract my vote.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get that line every time a pointcut is done by Spring AOP, you could

- pointcut all the AOP methods with a new pointcut
- make all pointcuts extend some super-pointcut

which you target to write that line.

If you want to have the AOP class write something when it gets loaded, you can use @BeforeClass to have it do something before the class gets used.